# MS Dos - Code written in batch file are not executed

Tags: batch-file

Wrote the below lines in a bat file but when I execute the batch file, the command prompt window opens and closes. It doesn't execute the below code.

```
for /L %y IN (0, 1, 10) DO (echo %y & echo %y & echo %y)
pause
```

Comment: MS-DOS does not understand `For` loops, so if you're really using that and not `cmd.exe`, in Windows, I'm not suprised that it is closing without executing!

Comment: Your first line of troubleshooting should be reading the help file for the command you are trying to execute.  If you would have read the first 8 lines of the help file for the `FOR` command you would have read this: **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.**

Comment: Please clarify: are you really working with MSDOS? It looks similar to the Windows Command Prompt, but is very different. MSDOS doesn't support `for /L` loops, `cmd` (Windows Command Line) does.

Comment: There is no `for /L` in MS-DOS – do you mean Windows Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0):

When executed directly from the prompt, `for %x in (list) do echo %x` is correct. Within a batch file however, all references to the `metavariable` **x** must use a double-`%`, so within a batch file, `for %%x in (list) do echo %%x` is correct.

Same, of course, goes for the *metavariable* `y`